# Why does this menu act screwy in IE? SOS

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, navigation

I hope someone can help. This is driving me nuts.

You can see the page i'm having problems with at [www.jomundayphotography.com/template.html](http://www.jomundayphotography.com/template.html).

The dropdown menu is working everywhere but Internet Explorer (all versions are having problems).

**The Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="css/navcss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="css/csstest2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


<script src="JavaScript/jq.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="JavaScript/easing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="JavaScript/color.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="JavaScript/navjs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="JavaScript/mainTest2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="container"> 

        <div id="header">
                <img src="images/Logos/logo.png" id="logo" alt="Sinclairs Solicitors Logo"/>
                <img src="images/Logos/conveyancingqualitylogo.gif" id="conveyancingQuality" alt="Conveyancing Quality"/>
        <div id="motto">
                        <p>

                            <span id="motto1">Professional</span>
                            <span id="motto2">Experienced</span>
                            <span id="motto3">Approachable</span>

                        </p>
                            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="nav"><div id="navBar"> 
            <ul> 
                <li id="aboutUsHeading"class="menuItem"><a href="#">about Us</a></li>

                <li id="teamMenuHeading" class="menuItem">
                    <a href="#">the team</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="subMenuItem"><a href="#">Henry Drucker</a></li>                                
                            <li class="subMenuItem"><a href="#">Joanna Yianni</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </li>

                <li id="servicesMenuHeading" class="menuItem">
                    <a href="#">services</a>
                         <ul>
                            <li class="subMenuItem"><a href="#">Residential Property</a></li>                            
                            <li class="subMenuItem"><a href="#">Commercial Property</a></li>
                            <li class="subMenuItem"><a href="#">Company Commercial</a></li>
                            <li class="subMenuItem"><a href="#">Landlord and Tenant</a></li>
                            <li class="subMenuItem"><a href="#">Wills</a></li>
                            <li class="subMenuItem"><a href="#">Trust and Probate</a></li>
                            <li class="subMenuItem"><a href="#">Family Life</a></li>
                            <li class="subMenuItem"><a href="#">Employment</a></li>
                            <li class="subMenuItem"><a href="#">General Litigation</a></li>
                            <li class="subMenuItem"><a href="#">Personal Injury</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </li>

                <li id="contactMenuHeading" class="menuItem"><a href="#">contact us</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="subMenuItem"> <a href="#">find us</a></li>
                        </ul> 
                 </li>
            </ul> 
        </div></div> <!--end of navBar-->

        <div id="content"> 
            <div class="contentBox" id="sideBarLeft">
                <div id="miniMenu"> 
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="ResidentialProperty.html"><nobr>Residential Property</nobr></a></li>
                        <li><a href="CommercialProperty.html"><nobr>Commercial Property</nobr></a></li>
                        <li><a href="CompanyCommercial.html"><nobr>Company Commercial</nobr></a></li>
                        <li><a href="LandlordTenant.html"><nobr>Landlord and Tenant</nobr></a></li>
                        <li><a href="Wills.html"><nobr>Wills</nobr></a></li>
                        <li><a href="TrustandProbate.html"><nobr>Trust and Probate</nobr></a></li>
                        <li><a href="FamilyLaw.html"><nobr>Family Law</nobr></a></li>
                        <li><a href="Employment.html"><nobr>Employment</nobr></a></li>
                        <li><a href="GeneralLitigation.html"><nobr>General Litigation</nobr></a></li>
                        <li><a href="PersonalInjury.html"><nobr>Personal Injury</nobr></a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div> 
            <div class="contentBox" id="galleryBox"> 
            <div id="contentHolder">
            <p id="p1">moving House?</p>

            <p id="p3">At Sinclairs we have over<br/>25 years experience,<br/>helping our clients<br/>through the moving process,<br/>advising on how to stay<br/>in control of their rented<br/>properties,and in all areas<br/>of legal documentation.</p> 
            <p id="p4">renting?</p>


            <p id="p7">need to make a Will?</p>



              <p id="contact">0208 203 3344 <br/>info@sinclairssolicitors.com<button class="myButton" email><a href="#">email us</a></button><br/>20 Watford Way, Hendon, NW4 3AD</p>



            <div>


            </div> 
            <div class="contentBox" id="galleryBox2">
                <!--<img id="image1" src="images/civillitigation2.jpg"class="top"/>-->
                            </div>
            <div class="contentBox" id="galleryBox3"><p></p><img src="images/speechbubble.png"><span>read what our clients have to say about us</span><div id="testimonialTeaser"></div></div>
        </div>   
</div>
</div>
</div> <!--container end-->
<div id="footertop"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**The CSS**

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
/* reset */
html, body, div, span, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    }

body {
    line-height: 1;
    }

ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
    }

blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
    }

blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
    }

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    }
/* @font-face @/ /* Generated by Font Squirrel (http://www.fontsquirrel.com) on May 2, 2011 04:30:37 PM America/New_York */
/* end reset*/

body {
    position:relative;
    background: url(../images/Backgrounds/bgtile1.gif);
    z-index: -30;
    overflow: scroll;
    }

#container {
    position:relative;
    top: 0px;
    width: 1002px;
    height:850px;
    margin: 20px auto 0px auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    /*border-right: 15px #18c662 solid;*/
    }

#header {
    position:relative;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    z-index:10;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 170px;
    background-image: url(../images/Backgrounds/headerbg.gif);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
        }

#logo {
    clear:both;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    float:left; 
    height: 140px;
    background: none;
    }   

#conveyancingQuality {
        float:right;
    height: 95px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    }
#motto {
    clear:both;
    position: absolute;
    line-height:.9;
    left: 470px;
    top: 30px;
    color: #000;
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: 'Ropa Sans', "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 1.3;
        }

#motto1 {
    display: none;
    }

#motto2 {
    display: none;
    margin-left: 40px;
        }   

#motto3 {
    display: none;
    margin-left: 70px;
        }

#navBar {
    clear:both;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;

        }


#navBar a {

    display: block;
    width: 238.5px;
    height: 18px;
    /*margin-right: 16.25px;
    margin-left: 16.25px;*/
    padding: 6px;
    border-right:0px #fff solid;
        text-decoration:none;
            background: url(../images/Buttons/buttona.png);
            height: 50px;
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            color: #000;
    font-family: 'Ropa Sans', "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size:1.8em;


}
#aboutUsHeading a {
    /*margin-left: 30.25px;*/
    }
#contactMenuHeading a{
    /*margin-right: 0px;*/
    border-right:0px #fff solid;
    }

#navBar a:hover {

    color: #039;
    color: rgba(21, 68, 86, .9);
    background: url(../images/Buttons/buttonb.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;

    }

#navBar li.menuItem {
    /*z-index:21;*/
    margin-top:-6px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-right:0px;
    float:left;
    line-height: 1.6;
    font-size:100%;
    height: 30px;

    border-right:0px #fff solid;

    }

.subMenuItem {
    position:relative;
    top: 0px;
    display: none;
    font-size:80%;
    text-indent: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    border-right:0px #fff solid;
    height: 50px;
    z-index:30;
        }
#navBar ul ul li a {
    height:30px;
    background: url(../images/Buttons/submenubuttona.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-size: 95%;
            }
#navBar ul ul li a:hover {
    background: url(../images/Buttons/submenubuttonb.png)
            }


#content {
    clear: both;
    z-index: 22;
    position: absolute;
    top: 235px;

    }
.contentBox {

    position: absolute;
    float:left;
    border: 1px #154456 solid;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 600px;
    /*background-image: url(../images/Backgrounds/contentbg2.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    /*-webkit-border-radius: 7px;
-moz-border-radius: 7px;
border-radius: 7px;*/
}

#sideBarLeft {
    position:relative;
    width: 1000px;
    }
#miniMenu {
    padding: 5px 0px;
    margin: 210px 0px 5px 13px;
    font-family: 'Ropa Sans', "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    background: none;
    width: 200px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
        }

#miniMenu a {

    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:110%;
    height: ;
    padding: 3px 3px 3px 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    width:90%;
    background-image: url(../images/Buttons/submenubuttona.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    color: #000;
    font-family: 'Ropa Sans', "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-indent:0px;



    }

#miniMenu a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: rgba(21, 68, 86, .9);
    background-image: url(../images/Buttons/submenubuttonb.png);
    font-style:italic;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
    }
#articleBox {
    left: 210px;
    width: 580px;

    }

#sideBarRight {
    left: 799px;
    width: 200px;
    }

 .contentBox, #container,  #content {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
    }

#galleryBox {
    positioning: absolute;
    top: 13px;
    left: 10px;
    height: 170px;
    width: 980px;
    background: url(../images/Backgrounds/dep_5272790-London-Skyline.png);
    }

#contentHolder{
    width: 550px;
    height:100%;
    background:#fff;
    margin-left:250px;
    z-index: 10
    }

#contentHolder p {
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 11;
    padding-top: 10px;
    }

#p1 {
    display: none;
    font-family: 'Droid Sans', "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 80%;
    color: #154456;
    margin-left: 470px;
    }

#p3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    display: none;
    margin-left: 320px;
    font-family: 'Droid Sans', "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    text-align:center;
    color: #154456;
    }

#p4 {
    display: none;
    font-family: 'Droid Sans', "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 80%;
    color: #154456;
    margin-left: 470px;
    }

#p7 {
    display: none;
    font-family: 'Droid Sans', "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 80%;
    color: #154456;
    margin-left: 470px;
    }

#contact {
    display: none;
    font-family: 'Droid Sans', "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 200%;
    color: #154456;
    margin-left: 0px;
    }

#contact a{
    color: #154456;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#contact a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#contactBox {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    position:absolute;
    top: 76px;
    background: #3F3
    }

.myButton {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ededed), color-stop(1, #154456) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ededed 5%, #154456 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ededed', endColorstr='#154456');
    background-color:#ededed;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #154456;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#f5f5f5;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:6px 24px;
    text-decoration:none;
}.myButton:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #154456), color-stop(1, #ededed) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #154456 5%, #ededed 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#154456', endColorstr='#ededed');
    background-color:#154456;
}.myButton:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}

#galleryBox2 img {;
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
            }   

#image2 {
    display: block;
    }

#image1 {
    display: block;
    }
#galleryBox2 img:hover {

    }

#galleryBox2 {
    positioning: absolute;
    top: 190px;
    left: 215px;
    height: 375px;
    width: 210px;
background-image: url(../images/Backgrounds/contentbg2.png);
    }
#galleryBox3 {
    positioning: absolute;
    top: 190px;
    left: 440px;
    height: 375px;
    width: 538px;
background-image: url(../images/Backgrounds/contentbg2.png);
    }
#testimonialTeaser {
    position: relative;
    top: 12px;
    background:none;
    /*background: #18c662;*/
    width: ;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;

    }
#footertop {
    margin: 40px 0px 0px 0px;
    background: url(../images/Backgrounds/footerbg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    height:75px;    
    }
#footer {
    background:#FFFFFF; 
    position:relative;
    top:75px;
    height:auto;
    }
```

**The JavaScript**

```
// JavaScript Document


$(document).ready(function() {
    var teamMenuHeading = $('#teamMenuHeading');
    var teamSubMenu = $('#teamMenuHeading li');
    var teamSubMenuLinks = $('#teamMenuHeading a');
    var buttonb = ['images/buttonb.gif'];
    //alert (teamSubMenu.length)
teamMenuHeading.hover(
            function(){
                teamSubMenu.stop(true,true).slideDown(700, 'easeOutSine' //, function() {

                                    )
                }, //end teamMenuHeading hover first function

            function(){
                teamSubMenu
                        .stop(true,true).slideUp(200, 'easeOutSine'//, function() {

                )



            }); //end teamMenuHeading hover


    var servicesMenuHeading = $('#servicesMenuHeading')
    var servicesSubMenu = $('#servicesMenuHeading li');
    var servicesSubMenuLinks = $('#servicesMenuHeading a');
//alert (servicesSubMenu.length)
servicesMenuHeading.hover(
            function(){
                    servicesSubMenu.stop(true,true).slideDown(700, 'easeOutSine' //, function() {

                                    )
                }, //end teamMenuHeading hover first function

            function(){
                servicesSubMenu
                        .stop(true,true).slideUp(200, 'easeOutSine'//, function() {

                )



            }); //end servicesMenuHeading hover


    var contactMenuHeading = $('#contactMenuHeading')
    var contactSubMenu = $('#contactMenuHeading li');
    var contactSubMenuLinks = $('#contactMenuHeading a');
//alert (servicesSubMenu.length)
contactMenuHeading.hover(
            function(){
                    contactSubMenu.stop(true,true).slideDown(700, 'easeOutSine' //, function() {

                                    )
                }, //end teamMenuHeading hover first function

            function(){
                contactSubMenu
                        .stop(true,true).slideUp(500, 'easeOutSine'//, function() {

                )



            }); //end contactMenuHeading hover

}); //end ready
```

Comment: You should first validate your page in http://validator.w3.org/ And you forgot `.com` in the URL

Comment: Looks buggy on Chrome 17.0.963.56. The menu appears behind the `galleryBox`.

Answer (score 1):

**Number 1 rule for styling lists:**

Reset your lists: `ul, li { margin:0;padding:0 }`

Do not style `LI`s, other than `display:`, `position:` and `float:`.

Use `display:block` and put **all styling** on your `A`-tag.

This will clear up 99% of list layout problems.

See my tutorial: http://preview.moveable.com/JM/ilovelists/

Comment: thanks for this info. do you think this would cuase the odd hover behaiviour?